# Enable and disable scroll based on boolean in SvelteKit?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, sveltekit

**The problem**
In SvelteKit, I am trying to disable and enable scroll when my side menu is opened. To do that, I am trying to utilize the {open} variable that is bound to my menu icon with bind:open={open}.
I want to trigger the function enableScroll() when open is true, and trigger the function disableScroll() when open is false.
Both functions work fine. The {open} variable is true when I expect it to, and false when I expect it to when I use console.log().
The problem is that my if-block doesn't respond to {open} changing.

**What I've tried**

- I have tried wrapping my if-block in another function and calling the function changeScroll() on:click.
- I have tried
  adapting the conditionals: if === true, true, open || null; similarly for the negation.
- I have tried using a ternary operator inside of the binding like so: on:click={open ? disableScroll() : enableScroll() }

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
    $: if (open === true) {
            onMount(() => {
                disableScroll()
            })
        } else if (open === false) {    
            onMount(() => {
                enableScroll()
            })
        }
```

Perhaps I'm using onMount() wrongly? Or somehow I need to change my if statement to make it properly reactive / fix it some other way? I would gladly appreciate some help! Thank you.

Comment: *"...onMount, which runs after the component is first rendered to the DOM"* Did you try it without onMount? [Like this](https://svelte.dev/repl/c12ce864f052459bb8ecc01d29c01fd7?version=3.44.1) it would work

Comment: The problem is that I need to use onMount somehow to access the window, which is used in both functions. So the example works, but the functions themselves won't...

Comment: Why is the window only accessibly inside onMount? Can you reproduce this in a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.44.1)?

Comment: In the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/32ed10cc870048d9b5aa366ad9dddc5d?version=3.44.2) it works, but in my local environment, and also after deploy, I get this: "ReferenceError: window is not defined".

Comment: You can change `$: open = open;` to simply `let open`. I'm not sure about user experience when disabling scrolling like this. There's still the scrollbar and in the REPL it's possible to scroll a bit but it will instantly be reset which feels kind of strange and makes one wonder why it behaves like this. Why not disabling scroll via CSS instead [like this](https://svelte.dev/repl/0880a3fde57144e0b59486d7882e3791?version=3.44.2)?

Comment: I think your method doesn't work on iOS. Still, when I implement it, I get a similar error: "ReferenceError: document is not defined". I think the problem is similar to the one described [here](https://fix.code-error.com/referenceerror-document-is-not-defined-in-svelte-3/) and lies within the use of the onMount function, but I can't get it to work...

Comment: Next try: what if you assign the window to a variable in onMount and pass it to the functions [like this](https://svelte.dev/repl/9f425ad311314fd7b63e0b620e45ee21?version=3.44.2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onMount` only [queues a function to run once](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount), when the component is mounted. So running `onMount(() => { disableScroll() })` will not run `disableScroll` if the component has already been rendered -- any subsequent changes to `open` will not have any affect. This is why your code doesn't work.

However, you do need to do something to prevent your scroll code from running on the server, since `window` isn't available there. In SvelteKit, you can determine whether you're in the browser by using the [browser import](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-env) from `$app/env`. This will tell you if it's safe to access browser-only APIs on the document or window. So, you could do something like the following:

```js
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { browser } from '$app/env';

    let open;

    let scrollTop = null;
    let scrollLeft = null;

    function disableScroll() {
        if (browser) {
            scrollTop = 
                window.pageYOffset || window.document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            scrollLeft = 
                window.pageXOffset || window.document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
                window.onscroll = function() {
                window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
            }};
        }

    function enableScroll() {
        if (browser) {
            window.onscroll = function() {};
        }
    };

    $: if (open) {
        disableScroll();
    } else {
        enableScroll();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes a lot of sense, because with onMount, it did actually work once and now I understand why. I learned something!

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty succinct way of doing this

```
<svelte:window on:wheel|nonpassive={e => {
    if(open)
        e.preventDefault()
}} />
```

and if you don't have a variable, for example if you wrap your side menu in a component you can skip the `if` condition

```
<svelte:window on:wheel|nonpassive|preventDefault />
```

i.e. block scroll if component is rendered.

and to go one step further in case you have a large side menu with the potential for overflow

```
<svelte:window on:wheel|nonpassive|preventDefault />
<SideMenu>
    <div on:wheel|stopPropagation>
```

will allow you to block all scroll events not related to your menu